# How to use Contains method to search within another collection?

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I have a list of `int`.

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 2};
```

Now, I have another list of `int`

```
List<int> numberListEnhanced = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6};
```

I have a LINQ query in which I am using WHERE and in that I need to check if `numberListEnhanced` contains the elements of the `numbersList`.

I have done for a single but for multiple cannot figure out.

For single:

```
.....where numberListEnhanced.Contains((int)s.Id));
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. What exactly is the result that you are aiming at? to you want a yes or no answer? Are `All` elements from `numberListEnhanced` contained in `numberList`  or vice versa? Or do you want to retrieve the numbers that satisfy this criterion ? These are 2 different questions, and for both there is an existing duplicate on StackOverflow. We will find it for you.

Comment: I removed some tags because what you ask is not related to entity framework or linq-to-sql (which, BTW, are very different technologies and not likely to coincide in a question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` (no duplicates):

```
var valuesInBothLists = numberList.Intersect(numberListEnhanced).ToList(); 

// result: 1 2 3
```

Or you can do this using `Where`:

```
var valuesInBothLists = numberList.Where(item => numberListEnhanced.Contains(item)).ToList();

// or 

var valuesInBothLists = from item in numberList
                        where numberListEnhanced.Contains(item)
                        select item;

// result: 1 2 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Intersect`:

```
IEnumerable<int> both = numberList.Intersect(numberListEnhanced);
```

**Check this**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check if `numberListEnhanced` contains the elements of the `numbersList`

Another way of approaching this is to reverse your thinking:

> I need to check if there are elements in `numbersList` that are *not* present in `numberListEnhanced`

If you find that there are elements in `numbersList` that are *not* present in `numberListEnhanced`, you know that `numberListEnhanced` does *not* contain all elements in `numbersList`.

One way to find all elements in `numbersList` that are *not* present in `numberListEnhanced` is to use [`.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0):

```csharp
var notPresentElements = numbersList.Except(numberListEnhanced);
```

From here, we can compute:

```csharp
var allElementsArePresent = !notPresentElements.Any();
```

to confirm (or disprove) that `numberListEnhanced` contains the elements of the `numbersList`.

Both `.Except()` and `.Any()` are from the namespace *System.Linq*.

**Note:**
Using `.Except()` will compare the element *sets* of the two collections, and produce an element *set* as a result. Examples:

- `{ 1, 2, 2 }.Except({ 1, 2 })` will produce `{ }`, even though `2` is repeated in the first collection
- `{ 1, 2, 3, 3 }.Except({ 1, 2 })` will produce `{ 3 }`, not `{ 3, 3 }`

If you need to take the repeated element count into account, you need to use another approach (or make additional checks for the repeated elements).

---

Using your example values,

```csharp
List<int> numbersList = new() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 2 };
List<int> numberListEnhanced = new() { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 };

var notPresentElements = numbersList.Except(numberListEnhanced);

var allElementsArePresent = !notPresentElements.Any();
```

`notPresentElements` will contain `{ 4, 8, 10 }` when enumerated.

In effect, `notPresentElements` will be `false`
--> `numberListEnhanced` does *not* contain all elements in `numbersList`.